# Erro ao formatar número no php

Tags: php

Eu tenho esté valor: `47830,60`

Quero deixar assim `47.830,60`. Para isso usei a função `number_format` assim:

`number_format($valor,2,",",".");`

mas me retorna este erro:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered

Obs: tentei um cast `float` mas está zerando os centavos.

Comment: Troque `47830,60` por `47830.60` e veja se resolve.

Comment: Obrigado!. Resolveu e usei a `str_replace` para fazer isso

Comment: Pode aproveitar e criar uma resposta à sua própria pergunta, explicando como resolveu e colocando o código. Assim acaba por ficar como referência para futuros leitores com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solução:

```
<?php echo "R$ ".number_format(str_replace(',', '.', $valor),2,',','.'); ?>
```

Explicação:

Como meu valor inicial tem uma vírgula para separar os centavos, precisei usar o `str_replace` para trocar a vírgula por um ponto e deixar o valor assim: `47830.60`. Com isso foi possível fazer o `number_formar` sem problemas.